# Word completion in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there some extension that lets me complete a word that you started typing with other words in the document?

When you activate the shortcut, it fills in with as many letters that it can. If you already have the words `abc` and `abk` in the document and you activate completion when you have written `a`, it should add `b`, but it cannot go further because it is not known if you want to write `abc` or `abk`.

- The operation should only use the keyboard
- You should not get a list of suggestions, just a simple completion
- If you activate the shortcut twice, nothing is added to the word the second time because it is already completed as long as possible. There would be no feedback either
- The operation should be one keypress only and work instantly